# Clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode 10, Xcode 10.1 Beta, Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode10, swift4.2

The project was working fine until I add these Cocoapods below:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'XXXXAPPNAME' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'KVNProgress'
pod 'OneSignal'
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'AKMaskField'

end
```

The result of pod installation:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AKMaskField (2.0.3)
Installing IQKeyboardManager (6.0.4)
Installing KVNProgress (2.3.1)
Installing OneSignal (2.8.5)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `APPNAME.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.
```

and then, of course, I run the project with **APPNAME.xcworkspace** file

But it gives an error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-foktozccazlvmoexywpkabjotonf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AKMaskField'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-foktozccazlvmoexywpkabjotonf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQKeyboardManager'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/MYNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-foktozccazlvmoexywpkabjotonf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KVNProgress'

ld: framework not found AKMaskField

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have googled it. I have read all questions/replies about the same topic in here StackOverflow. but I could not find a solution. I have removed derived Data also. It did not work.

Comment: Dear @Kamran Actually, I was thinking about this but I thought, "No way, they must be updated it. Now, I am sure. Thanks. Kamran, Question: How can I mark your comment as a reply? Otherwise, this question is monitoring in here an unsolved question. Or can you mark your comment as a reply if it is possible, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There libraries are not updated for `Swift 4.2`. This issue comes for any library that is missing the version attribute(`s.swift_version = '4.2'`) in `.podspec` file. Also `.swift-version` is deprecated so that also needs to be removed for any of the pod. Now, either you can open issues so the developers can update their libraries for `Swift 4.2` or you can fork and make the changes yourself and then point your repo. in pods. Last option is to use `Xcode 9.4.1` until libraries are not updated.